# AutoIT: ControlGetText doesn't get the whole text

Tags: autoit

[image]

I am trying to get the text on the edit of the combobox, but it returns only the first word and not the remaining.

```
WinWaitActive("Properties")
Sleep(500)
$select = ControlGetText("Properties", "", "[CLASS:ComboBox; INSTANCE:1]")
MsgBox(0, "", $select)
```

Comment: Why not use `_GUICtrlComboBox_GetEditText`?

Comment: I've tried that and it returns nothing, as in blank.There is a combo box which displays the file name and file type of a file. When I try to display the text of the combobox, it only returns the file name. I just figured out, using Window Info Tool , than the only visible text is the file name and the file type is neither visible nor hidden.

Comment: what application is this for, or is there a standard windows application that shows the same behaviour? Alternatively, could you take some screen shots and get some more information about it.

Comment: It is the first app I've seen with this behavior. I just uploaded the screenshot of the combobox and info of it. Thanks.

Comment: Yep, that's not a standard control, so standard functions won't do it. The JPEG string is probably owner drawn, so I don't think there is any way to read this apart from OCR perhaps.

Comment: Right. Thank you anyways, you've been a big help. :)

Comment: Can you catch the text via ctrl+c? Maybe this way could work. Besides, you needn't the Sleep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just so this question can be closed as answered:

The JPEG part of that control is most likely owner drawn, it certainly isn't part of the standard control. As a result the standard control functions will not work on it.

The only remaining options are reading the program memory directly (depending on the language it was written in, and how the string is stored, that could be quite easy or practically impossible), or OCR. There are a number of OCR libraries made for AutoIt, just search the forums.